# Powershell scripting using where-object

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a powershell script for Exchange Management Shell, importing a list of contacts from a csv file into a distribution group.

I start out with

```
Import-csv C:\filename.csv | forEach-Object {New-MailContact .......}
```

This works well, except that some entries in my csv file have a blank email address, and the create teh new contact craps out because ExternalEmailAddress is blank.  So, I tried:

```
Import-csv C:\filename.csv | ForEach-Object { Where-Object {$_.ExternalEmailAddress -ne "" } | New-MailContact -Name $_.Name -ExternalEmailAddress $_.ExternalEmailAddress....}
```

But that didn't seem to work - it didn't filter out the entries with blank email addresses.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you might want to use `Where-Object` prior to `ForEach-Object` because it will filter the objects passed along the pipeline.

Depending on what the New-MailContact cmdlet supports you might be able to pipe the results directly into it or you may have to pass them one by one.

All at once (NOT using `ForEach-Object`):

```
Import-csv C:\filename.csv | Where-Object {$_.ExternalEmailAddress -ne "" } | New-MailContact -Name $_.Name -ExternalEmailAddress $_.ExternalEmailAddress }
```

One by one (by using `ForEach-Object`):

```
Import-csv C:\filename.csv | Where-Object {$_.ExternalEmailAddress -ne "" } | ForEach-Object { New-MailContact -Name $_.Name -ExternalEmailAddress $_.ExternalEmailAddress }
```

Comment: No, I tried that, and got an error -New-MailContact : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is null.
At line:1 char:106
+ Import-csv c:\FloridaBarTest.csv | Where-Object {$_.ExternalEmailAddress -ne ""} |  New-MailContact -Name  <<<< $_.Name -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.FirstName -ExternalEmailAddress $_.ExternalEmailAddress -OrganizationalUnit "FloridaBarContacts"    it seems like the csv contents aren't getting passed through the pipeline.

Comment: What error(s) are you receiving? Can you update the question with a bit more information?

Comment: It might be good to validate the members of the PSObject being passed  through the pipeline to make sure you're accessing them. 

To do this, pipe the results of Import-Csv to Get-Member

Comment: Not sure what New-MailContact cmdlet supports on the pipeline so I updated the answer with possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Could be there's actually a space or some other white space character there, and they're not actully null.  Maybe something like this:

```
 Import-csv C:\filename.csv | Where-Object {$_.ExternalEmailAddress -match "^\S+$" } | New-MailContact -Name $_.Name -ExternalEmailAddress $_.ExternalEmailAddress....}
```